# global_planner fails to find a plan - It doesn't search certain regions on the map

Tags: ros, global-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[image: RVIZ potential]

Here is the situation in the above picture. The robot is between a sofa and a wall, and it is facing upwards. I am setting a goal in the bigger room (right part of the map), and `global_planner` fails to produce a path. The visualization of global_planner's potential shows that it didn't even search in the big room.

What led to this behavior, i.e. graph search doesn't cover the region involving the goal? How do we correct it?

Some info: `use_dijlstra` is set to true (default).

Thanks!

EDIT: My parameters:

### move_base

```
# Choose planners                                            
base_local_planner: "dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS"        
base_global_planner: "global_planner/GlobalPlanner"          
                                                             
# Using default recovery behaviors                           
                                                             
# Timeouts and frequencies                                   
controller_frequency: 10.0                                   
controller_patience: 15.0                                    
                                                             
planner_frequency: 2.0 #global plan | 0.25 #2.0              
planner_patience: 5.0                                        
                                                             
oscillation_timeout: 10.0                                    
oscillation_distance: 0.2                                    
                                                             
# Other params                                               
shutdown_costmaps: false                                     
                                              
# global_planner params                                      
GlobalPlanner:                                               
  default_tolerance: 0.2                                     
  cost_factor: 0.5489                                        
  neutral_cost: 66                                           
  lethal_cost: 253
```

### costmap

```
global_frame: /map
robot_base_frame: /base_footprint
map_type: voxel

# Robot definition
# Even wider
# footprint: [[-0.495, 0.145], [-0.105, 0.366], [0.154, 0.374], [0.357, 0.154], [0.357, -0.154], [0.154, -0.374], [-0.105, -0.366], [-0.495, -0.145]]
# Wider
# footprint: [[-0.483, 0.121], [-0.092, 0.343], [0.132, 0.343], [0.349, 0.136], [0.349, -0.136], [0.132, -0.343], [-0.090, -0.343], [-0.483, -0.121]]
# Narrower
footprint: [[-0.42951, -0.10764], [-0.08274, -0.30298], [0.11447, -0.30298], [0.30577, -0.12000], [0.30577, 0.12000], [0.11447, 0.30298], [-0.08407, 0.30298], [-0.42951, 0.10764]]

map_layer:
  map_topic: /map


nogo_layer:
  map_topic: /map_nogo


inflation_layer:
  inflation_radius: 1.75
  cost_scaling_factor: 2.58


obstacle_layer:
  max_obstacle_height: 2.0
  obstacle_range: 2.5
  raytrace_range: 3.0

  origin_z: -0.2
  z_resolution: 0.15
  z_voxels: 12
  unknown_threshold: 8
  mark_threshold: 0

  publish_voxel_map: true

  observation_sources: laser xtion_obstacles xtion_clear xtion_back_obstacles xtion_back_clear

  laser:           {topic: /scan, data_type: LaserScan, sensor_frame: laser_link, marking: true, clearing: true, min_obstacle_height: 0.25, max_obstacle_height: 0.35}
  xtion_obstacles: {topic: /xtion_qqvga/depth/points_clipped, data_type: PointCloud2, marking: true, clearing: false, min_obstacle_height: 0.1, max_obstacle_height: 0.9, observation_persistence: 0.0, obstacle_range: 2.0}
  xtion_clear:     {topic: /xtion_qqvga/depth/points_max, data_type: PointCloud2, marking: false, clearing: true, min_obstacle_height: -0.1, max_obstacle_height: 1.1, observation_persistence: 0.0, raytrace_range: 5.0}
  xtion_back_obstacles: {topic: /xtion_back_qqvga/depth/points_clipped, data_type: PointCloud2, marking: true, clearing: false, min_obstacle_height: 0.1, max_obstacle_height: 0.9, observation_persistence: 0.0, obstacle_range: 2.0}
  xtion_back_clear: {topic: /xtion_back_qqvga/depth/points_max, data_type: PointCloud2, marking: false, clearing: true, min_obstacle_height: -0.1, max_obstacle_height: 1.1, observation_persistence: 0.0, raytrace_range: 5.0}

local_costmap:
  update_frequency: 5.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 4.0
  height: 4.0
  resolution: 0.02
  plugins:  
    - {name: obstacle_layer, type: "costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"}
    - {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

global_costmap:
  update_frequency: 5.0
  static_map: true
  rolling_window: false
  plugins:  
    - {name: map_layer, type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
    - {name: nogo_layer, type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
    - {name: obstacle_layer, type: "costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"}
    - {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247908/global_planner-fails-to-find-a-plan---it-doesn%27t-search-certain-regions-on-the-map/) by [zkytony](https://answers.ros.org/users/26716/zkytony/) on ROS Answers with karma: 178 on 2016-11-11

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-11-15**:
Have you experimented with the global_planner's `allow_unknown` and the costmap's (obstacle layer) `track_unknown_space` parameters?

**Comment by [zkytony](https://answers.ros.org/users/26716/zkytony/) on 2016-11-15**:
I haven't.  It may reduce search space if I set `allow_unknown` to be false.  Theoretically they shouldn't affect whether a path could be found right?  I did some experiment with `cost_factor`, `neutral_cost` and they seem to have an effect on whether a path could be found. But still, not consistent

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-11-15**:
Is the door to the big room wider than "2x circumscribed radius" ? (see http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/hydro/inflation) Related to this, have you tried reducing `inflation_radius` ? `1.75` looks very high to me. However, none of these would explain the funky shape of the potential around the door.

**Comment by [zkytony](https://answers.ros.org/users/26716/zkytony/) on 2016-11-17**:
Hi spmaniato. The reason I set inflation radius to a quite high value is because I want the cost decay curve to be smoother. That way when the robot plans a path in a corridor, the path should be along the middle of the corridor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know how you did this.
but apparently, the parameter `cost_factor` and `neutral_cost`  are not loaded in source code. they are invalid, except you changed the source code.
Obviously, you should check the environment and your parameters settings, especially the inflation_radius. maybe too large to caculate the path.

---

Originally posted by [asimay_y](https://answers.ros.org/users/20955/asimay_y/) with karma: 255 on 2017-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0